# Android Firebase & Play Services library conflicts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Libraries are conflicting when I integrate working code module of firebase with my project which has Google Play services.

My project code was in Eclipse and I have imported it into Android Studio.

Comment: Please provide: what libraries are conflicting and error messages.

Comment: show us your gradle, manifest and maybe lib/ subfolder if present

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Comment: maybe you've added the firebase dependencies more than once.

Comment: There are Jar files in the `libs` folder that you need to remove.

Comment: refer [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to setup firebase